# Custom Round number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am using decimal numbers with 2 precision point (ie. 1.38). I want to round the number according to that following:

1) If the second precision point is larger or equal to 8 (1.38 or 1.39), then round it to 1.4, else don't change.

How can I do that in Javascript. toFixed doesn't work well because it rounds 1.75 to 1.8, which is not what I want.

Comment: I think you'll have to convert all the numerals to strings and round it up/down manually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres a rather clunky way of doing it:

```
var round = function(n) {
    var h = (n * 100) % 10;
    return h >= 8
        ? n + (10 - h) * .01
        : n;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way:

```
function customRound(n){
  var r = (((n+.02)*10)>>>0)/10;
  return r>n?r:n;
}

console.log(customRound(1.38));// 1.4
console.log(customRound(1.37999999999));// 1.37999999999
```

Have fun~